# how to check if a linked list is empty

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm new to C and have a question.

How would I check if a linked list is empty?

I have a struct _node

```
typedef struct _node{
    int data;
    struct _node *next;
}node;
```

If I have initialized `node *list`, but didn't do anything to it (i.e didn't assign `list->data` a value), how would I check if it's empty?

I tried `if (node == NULL){break}` but didn't work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Generally, you'd leave list = NULL until some data is inserted. At which point, you'd allocate a node, assign list to the memory, set the data member and make the next member NULL. Similarly when deleteing the list, you'd set list to NULL after removing the last piece of data.

Answer (score 7):

**Intro:**

There are usually two ways to use linked lists: with a root element and without.

Without a root, your list pointer is NULL when the list is empty:

```
node *list;
...
if (list == NULL) { /* empty list */ }
```

With root, there is always one element. But it can be used in two ways:

Either simply to provide a pointer to the first element.

```
node *root;
...
if (root->next == NULL) { /* empty list */ }
```

Or to have the last element link back to the root to form a cycle. This concept has the advantage that the "next" element is never NULL and you thus don't need to check for it. In this case, the list is empty if the root points back to itself.

```
node *root;
...
if (root->next == root) { /* empty list */ }
```

---

**Answer:**

Now, according to your description, you have allocated a node. This either means you want the "root" approach (second or third example). But if you want to go with the first variant, you must not allocate the node, since it doesn't hold data.

For the "root" approach, you indeed have one (and only one) node that doesn't hold data. But for simple linked lists, all nodes must contain data.

Answer (score 1):

I'd keep it simple.

Check the head pointer - if it is NULL, there's no entry in the list.

```
int isEmpty( node * list )
 {
   if( !list )
      return 1;
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Would do the same, or `return list == NULL ? 1 : 0;` ;)

Comment: Or, even shorter: `return !list;` :-)

Comment: @pzaenger,@DarkDust: Agreed, but the two more lines should make it more self explanatory for a C newbie ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you create a variable, C will zero out all the data for you.  Other times, the variable will contain garbage.  You need to learn the rules that govern this, but as a beginner, you should simply be certain always to initialize your variables explicitly.

For a linked list, when you append a node to a list, you should always be certain to set a `NULL` into the `next` pointer, so that the list will be properly terminated.

Your linked list should have a "head" pointer.  If the head is set to `NULL` then you have a zero-length linked list; if the head has any value other than `NULL` you must have at least one node in the linked list, so the list must have length of at least 1.

So, as long as you have been careful about initializing your head pointer to `NULL` you can trivially tell whether the list is empty by checking to see if the head pointer is `NULL`.

But your question was really about the `data` member variable.  There will always be some sort of value in there.  As I said, sometimes C will set it to zero for you, but other times it will be unpredictable garbage (a value that could be any integer value).  You need to initialize that to a sensible default when you allocate a new node.  For example, the valid values of `data` might all be greater than zero, so you might set `data` to zero to indicate that it is currently empty.

You can write a simple loop that traverses your linked list and checks each `data` member, and return true if it finds any `data` that is not zero (or whatever special value flags that it is unused).  It should return false if it finds only default `data` or if the list is zero length.

Answer (score -1):

Its better to have a **header** node when building your linked list. Then you can add nodes to build the list. Let that list variable be your header node. Then to check if your linked list is empty, use this:

```
typedef struct _node{
    int data;
    struct _node *next;
}*node;
```

and then instantiate

```
node list;
```

and **to check the linked list is empty** use

```
if((list->next)==null)
{
         break;
}
```

Comment: Hm, if you're not going for the "cycle" concept with a root/header node, what would be the advantage of having a header instead of just using a variable? I have listed this variant in my answer, but I fail to see it's use-case/advantage. So, can you explain what the advantage of a header node (without the cycle) would be over just using a variable directly?

Comment: The header node can be used to store important data, including the number of nodes in the list, which might prove useful in scenarios of very long lists or array of linked lists and such complex situations.